# How to use keyboard commands using sendKeys in CasperJS

Tags: javascript, casperjs

I want to use left arrow key (keyboard) in CasperJS. Please tell me how to use this one.  The scenario is I am adding one line in the cell and I want to place the cursor between the cells so that I can split the cell in to two halves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

below code might help you

```
var z = casper.evaluate(function triggerKeyDownEvent() {
            jQuery(unique selector).text("S3456bg");
            var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
            e.which = 13;
            e.keyCode = 13;
            jQuery(unique selector).trigger(e);
            return true;
});
```

Answer (score 4):

`sendKeys` doesn't support sending key, but only characters that can be represented in a string. The easiest would be to use the underlying PhantomJS function: [`sendEvent`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/send-event.html):

```
casper.sendKeys("yourSelector", "", {keepFocus: true});
casper.page.sendEvent("keypress", casper.page.event.key.Left);
```

Comment: thanks, but i don't have to initialize anything in variable right?

Comment: What variable? There is none that I can see.

Comment: regarding keyboard related code..because earlier i tried some thing so asking

Comment: What did you try? Are there problems with my suggestion? (I don't understand what you're taking about)

Comment: casper.sendKeys("/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div[2]/div[2]/div", "123", {keepFocus: true});
    casper.page.sendEvent("keypress", casper.page.event.key.Enter);

Comment: ya i checked your code it is working but when i used the same piece with enter button instead LEft arrow key it is not working

Comment: Please register to the [`resource.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#resource-error), [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error), [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`casper.page.onResourceTimeout`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/handler/on-resource-timeout.html) events. Maybe there are errors.

Comment: sorry i didn't get you...so please suggest me how to do this one. As i am very much new to casperjs

Comment: You can register to events using `casper.on`: e.g.`casper.on("remote.message", function(msg){ console.log(msg)})`

Comment: And how to use Shift+Home and then backspace key @Artjom B

Comment: @GANA Read the documentation for `page.sendEvent()`. You can specify the Home key and pass a modifier.

Comment: This works beautifully. Thanks Artjom. It should be the accepted answer (cc: @GANA).